# How does it unambiguously arise that the request comes from your application?

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, authentication, discord

I'm making an API(ASP.NET Core) and server in SignalR and want only my app to be able to access the servers.
To prevent third-party developers from creating their own custom applications and using my servers.
How did TeamSpeak 3 or Discord ensure that anyone can't create their own Discord client and use it to connect to servers?

Comment: Read into CORS headers and/or authentication/tokens.

Comment: @TinNguyen 
Can't they be faked?

Comment: Authentication/tokens are unique. If you know the token/password/whatever sure but it is a secret.